# MySQL database slowing down

Tags: mysql, performance

I need some help figuring out a performance issue. A database containing a single table with a growing number of METARs (aviation weather reports) is slowing down after about 8 million records are present. This despite indexes being in use. Performance can be recovered by rebuilding indexes, but that's really slow and takes the database offline, so I've resorted to just dropping the table and recreating it (losing the last few weeks of data).

The behaviour is the same whether a query is run trying to retrieve an actual metar, or whether a simple `select count(*)` is executed.

The table creation syntax is as follows:

```
CREATE TABLE `metars` (
  `id` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `tstamp` timestamp NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  `metar` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `icao` char(7) DEFAULT NULL,
  `qnh` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `timestamp` (`tstamp`),
  KEY `icao` (`icao`),
  KEY `qnh` (`qnh`),
  KEY `metar` (`metar`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=812803050 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

Up to about 8 million records, a `select count(*)` returns in about 500ms. Then it gradually increases, currently again at 14 million records, the count takes between 3 and 30 seconds. I was surprised to see that when explaining the count query, it's using the timestamp as an index, not the primary key. Using the primary key this should be a matter of just a few ms to return the number of records:

```
mysql> explain select count(*) from metars;
+----+-------------+--------+-------+---------------+-----------+---------+------+----------+-------------+
| id | select_type | table  | type  | possible_keys | key       | key_len | ref  | rows     | Extra       |
+----+-------------+--------+-------+---------------+-----------+---------+------+----------+-------------+
|  1 | SIMPLE      | metars | index | NULL          | timestamp | 5       | NULL | 14693048 | Using index |
+----+-------------+--------+-------+---------------+-----------+---------+------+----------+-------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

Forcing it to use the primary index is even slower:

```
mysql> select count(*) from metars use index(PRIMARY);
+----------+
| count(*) |
+----------+
| 14572329 |
+----------+
1 row in set (37.87 sec)
```

Oddly, the typical use case query is to get the weather for an airport nearest to a specific point in time which continues to perform very well, despite being more complex than a simple count:

```
mysql> SELECT qnh, metar from metars WHERE icao like 'KLAX' ORDER BY ABS(TIMEDIFF(tstamp, STR_TO_DATE('2019-10-10 00:00:00', '%Y-%m-%d %H:%i:%s'))) LIMIT 0,1;
+------+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| qnh  | metar                                                                                   |
+------+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| 2980 | KLAX 092353Z 25012KT 10SM FEW015 20/14 A2980 RMK AO2 SLP091 T02000139 10228 20200 56007 |
+------+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
1 row in set (0.01 sec)
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: The reason your limit is faster is because MySQL handles limits really effectively. You are also filtering rows down with your where parameter, so it can immediately throw out rows it doesn’t need. 30 seconds to load millions of indexed records isn’t unheard of, though the question might become one of architecture. Indexes make certain things faster, but are not a fix-all. Check also your table caching settings, it might be a memory issue on the environment.

Comment: MySQL might be the wrong tool for the job with that number. A key value database might better in this circumstance – they come with their own problems, but for what you’re trying to do it might be easier. Also as well as caching on the database, possibly your application should also have caching to protect the database from being hit.

Comment: According to [this page](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/184685/why-is-count-slow-when-explain-knows-the-answer), ``COUNT(*)`` is slow on InnoDB tables because it uses a table scan. Out of curiosity, have you tried ``COUNT(id)``?

Comment: The execution speed for `count(*)` just depends on how many bytes you read. Using the primary key means reading the complete table, using an index with less columns means reading less bytes (while the number of entries is the same, and that's all you want to know for `count(*)`). If you hit a performance barrier consistently, you may need more memory/check your memory settings: simplifying a bit, your cache may only have "space for 8 million rows", once you have more, MySQL needs to start reading from hdd, slowing it down. Check e.g. [performance stats](https://dba.stackexchange.com/q/56494)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

InnoDB performs a plain `COUNT(*)` by traversing some index.  It prefers the smallest index because that will require touching the least number of blocks.

The `PRIMARY KEY` is clustered with the data, so that index is actually the biggest.

What version are you using?  `TIMESTAMP` changed at some point.  Perhaps that explains why `tstamp` is used instead of `qnh`.

If you are purging old data by using `DELETE`, see http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/partitionmaint for a faster way.

I assume the data is static; that is it is never `UPDATEd`?  Consider building and maintaining a summary table, perhaps indexed by date.  This could have various counts for each day.  Then a fetch from that table would be much faster than hitting the raw data.  More:  http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/summarytables

How many rows for KLAX?  That query must fetch all of them in order to convert the timestamp before doing the LIMIT.  If you had `INDEX(icao, tstamp)`, you could find the next before or after a given time even faster.